# r to.period indexAt firstof does not work with period hours

Tags: r

Applying the R function to.period() to an univariate xts object with option indexAt = firstof does not work as expected.

```
head(USOil)
                      [,1]
2022-01-02 23:01:00 75.740
2022-01-02 23:01:00 75.740
2022-01-02 23:02:00 75.807
2022-01-02 23:03:00 75.688
2022-01-02 23:04:00 75.659
2022-01-02 23:05:00 75.661

head(to.period(USOil, "hours", indexAt = "firstof"))

                    USOil.Open USOil.High USOil.Low USOil.Close
2022-01-02 23:59:00     75.740     75.900    75.646      75.828
2022-01-03 00:59:00     75.827     76.069    75.805      75.946
2022-01-03 01:59:00     75.926     75.981    75.586      75.638
2022-01-03 02:59:00     75.658     75.658    75.476      75.498
2022-01-03 03:59:00     75.498     75.886    75.498      75.859
2022-01-03 04:59:00     75.818     75.854    75.756      75.764
```

That's not the result expected, it's according to indexAt = lastof, with indexAt = firstof it should be:

```
                    USOil.Open USOil.High USOil.Low USOil.Close
2022-01-02 23:00:00     75.740     75.900    75.646      75.828
2022-01-03 00:00:00     75.827     76.069    75.805      75.946
2022-01-03 01:00:00     75.926     75.981    75.586      75.638
2022-01-03 02:00:00     75.658     75.658    75.476      75.498
2022-01-03 03:00:00     75.498     75.886    75.498      75.859
2022-01-03 04:00:00     75.818     75.854    75.756      75.764
```

However, indexAt = startof works as expected but I can't use it as workaround because esp. on Sundays trading starts 1 minute later so it looks similar to:

```
head(to.period(USOil, "hours", indexAt = "startof"))
                    USOil.Open USOil.High USOil.Low USOil.Close
2022-01-02 23:01:00     75.740     75.900    75.646      75.828
2022-01-03 00:00:00     75.827     76.069    75.805      75.946
2022-01-03 01:00:00     75.926     75.981    75.586      75.638
2022-01-03 02:00:00     75.658     75.658    75.476      75.498
2022-01-03 03:00:00     75.498     75.886    75.498      75.859
2022-01-03 04:00:00     75.818     75.854    75.756      75.764
```

That causes problems in evaluations elsewhere.

Any ideas why indexAt = firstof does not work?

Thanks!

BTW: I read in a similar question here that the option indexAt should work only on periods monthly and quarterly but neither is anything like this documented, nor should index = startof work then, I think.

Comment: You mention `on.period`, is that a typo or a function from some other package?

Comment: sorry, I meant to.period() of course...